# How do I pivot multiple choice values into 1 row per object?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the following resultset (table `b`)

```
ObjectNumber  Value          Field
-----------------------------------
1             Yes            Field1
1             Foo bar baz    Field1
1             Lorem Ipsum    Field1
2             Yes            Field1
2             Foo bar baz    Field1
```

I am trying to pivot this output as follows:

```
select
      ObjectNumber
    , [Yes]
    , [Foo bar baz]
    , [Lorem Ipsum]
from
    b
pivot
(
    Field for Value in
    (
          [Yes]
        , [Foo bar baz]
        , [Lorem Ipsum]

    )
) u
```

Expecting an output like:

```
ObjectNumber Yes  [Foo bar baz] [Lorem Ipsum]
---------------------------------------------
1            1    1             1
2            1    1             null
```

But this gives an error: `incorrect syntax near '[Yes]'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like This

```
select
      ObjectNumber
    , [Yes]
    , [Foo bar baz]
    , [Lorem Ipsum]
from
    t
pivot
(
    count(Field)
    for Value  in ([Yes],[Foo bar baz],[Lorem Ipsum])

) u
```

Comment: Thanks! I now get the expected output. What I don't understand howerver, is the aggregate function. Does getting a `max()` or `count()` in this case make sense? How should I interpret the syntax?